# Sweet Alert cant add spinner on Swal.update

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

Im using sweet alert 2 with angular 9 ("sweetalert2": "^9.7.2" on my package.json).

Im not able to add a spinner (loading gif) inside a Swal.update

It was easy on Swal.fire just like this:

```
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Iniciando...',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      allowEscapeKey: false,
      allowEnterKey: false,

      onBeforeOpen: () => {
        Swal.showLoading();
      }
    });
```

After that fire, I want to update the info on that alert, as I update it with new info coming from the backend.

So, I do something like this:

```
 Swal.update({
          title: this.requestStatusPipe.transform(status),
          text: details
        });
```

The title and text are refreshed each second.

I've tried adding lot of things **inside** the update to show a spinner, but didnt work. For ex:

```
  onBeforeOpen: () => {
    Swal.showLoading();
  }
```

also used

```
onRender: () => {
        Swal.showLoading();
      }
```

And

```
        Swal.showLoading();
```

after the Swal.update.
Nothing worked.

I've read all of https://sweetalert2.github.io/ and no example of this.

Any idea?

---

**OBS (and update)**: I've inspected the elements, and I realize now that is due to some style issue. Somehow, the spinner style is changing from

```
<button type="button" class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled" aria-label="" disabled="" style="display: inline-block; border-left-color: rgb(48, 133, 214); border-right-color: rgb(48, 133, 214);">OK</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled" aria-label="" disabled="" style="display: inline-block; border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">OK</button>
```

As anyone can see, the border colors are automatically changing from rgb(48, 133, 214) to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) without any explanation, making the spinner invisible.

Any idea of why this is happening and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug from Sweet Alert. It has been solved on version 9.10.13.
Here is the issue: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/1957